# Разница между row_number, limit или rownum в разных базах данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, oracle

Разные базы данных предлагают разные варианты ограничения результата выборки по количеству записей.
Например, в PostgreSQL это limit, в Oracle может использоваться rownum. Но при этом есть row_number теоретически поддерживаемый всеми базами данных.

Есть ли разница между использованием специфичного варианта на каждой базе данных или же использованием общего row_number для всех, не задумываясь о типе базы данных?

То есть, возможно, под капотом базы реализуют эти варианты одинаково или же какие-то из вариантов заметно лучше, какие-то заметно хуже.

Comment: *Есть ли разница между использованием специфичного варианта на каждой базе данных или же использованием общего row_number для всех, не задумываясь о типе базы данных?* ROW_NUMBER невозможно использовать непосредственно. Только из CTE.

Comment: google.com Вам в руки

Comment: @Akina _ROW_NUMBER невозможно использовать непосредственно. Только из CTE_, но иногда  [получается](https://dbfiddle.uk/tgYA9pUc) и без CTE.

Comment: @0xdb Ну ещё и в ORDER BY можно. К тому же оно хоть как-то на использование похоже - в отличие от получения на выходе.